# AuthenticationInterceptor(Alamofire5.2) retry process doesn't work well

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a question about the AuthenticationInterceptor added in Alamofire 5.2.
I am using AuthenticationInterceptor to refresh the oAuth token.
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#authenticationinterceptor

The code I'm trying is below.

```swift
struct OAuthCredential: AuthenticationCredential {
    let accessToken: String
    let refreshToken: String
    let userID: String
    let expiration: Date

    // Require refresh if within 5 minutes of expiration
    var requiresRefresh: Bool { Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60 * 5) > expiration }
}


class OAuthAuthenticator: Authenticator {
    func apply(_ credential: OAuthCredential, to urlRequest: inout URLRequest) {
        urlRequest.headers.add(.authorization(bearerToken: credential.accessToken))
    }

    func refresh(_ credential: OAuthCredential,
                 for session: Session,
                 completion: @escaping (Result<OAuthCredential, Error>) -> Void) {
        
        // Request to refresh token
        let request = Session.default.request(
            URL(string: "URL for token refresh")!,
            method: .patch,
            parameters: ["refresh_token": credential.refreshToken]
        )
        
        request.responseJSON { response in
            // Get new Credential information
            // ~~~~~~
            completion(.success(newCredential))
        }
    }

    func didRequest(_ urlRequest: URLRequest,
                    with response: HTTPURLResponse,
                    failDueToAuthenticationError error: Error) -> Bool {
        return response.statusCode == 401
    }

    func isRequest(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, authenticatedWith credential: OAuthCredential) -> Bool {
        let bearerToken = HTTPHeader.authorization(bearerToken: credential.accessToken).value
        return urlRequest.headers["Authorization"] == bearerToken
    }
}

// ~~~~~~
let session = Session.default
let urlRequest = try! URLRequest(
    url: URL(string: "https://api.example/docs")!,
    method: .get
)
        
        
session.request(urlRequest, interceptor: interceptor).responseJSON { response in
    // ~~~~~
}
```

What I don't know is whether **didRequest** and **isRequest** are sometimes called. I debugged while pasting a breakpoint when I got a 401 error, but it didn't stop at the above method.

The reason those methods weren't called was that they would always be returned on the line below.
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/4f72b95b49c22e445e1866712f719698fa11c30c/Source/AuthenticationInterceptor.swift#L297
I couldn't find a case that didn't go through this line.

I would like to know the case where two methods are called.

Comment: Did you add your credentials in the interceptor? let interceptor = AuthenticationInterceptor(authenticator: authenticator, credential: credentials, refreshWindow: window)

Answer (score 0):

try to call a `.validate()`

```swift
    session.request(urlRequest, interceptor: interceptor).validate().responseJSON { response in
        // ~~~~~
    }
```